# Why can't they visit each other?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

At the end of *Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End*, Will Turner gets bound to the ship and Elizabeth waits for his return every 10 years. My question is twofold:

Firstly, we see throughout the movie that it's possible to live for short amounts of time aboard the *Flying Dutchman*. Why can't Elizabeth come aboard for a visit here and there?

Secondly, we also see that Davy Jones was able to come ashore with a bucket of seawater, why can't Will do the same?

Answer (score 8):

### Because he is busy doing his job, to ferry souls lost at sea to the afterlife.

Keep in mind that Davy Jones should also have been doing this. However, after Calypso *betrayed* him, he abandoned his duties, and that's why he started turning into a monster.

From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Dutchman_(Pirates_of_the_Caribbean)),

> As explained in the movie, the character of Davy Jones was given the Flying Dutchman by Calypso, his lover, to ferry souls lost at sea to the afterlife. When she neglected to meet him after his first ten years of duty, he was both heartbroken and enraged. He abandoned his duties and chose to wander the seas, doing as he pleased. This violation of his duty placed a curse on Jones and his crew, slowly transforming them into monsters.

Comment: He cant take a night off?

Comment: The sea does not rest, why should he? He gets a night off, tho... *every 10 years*